# Neural Networks: adding features improved training set accuracy but not validation set accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I added a few more features that are highly linked with class of which they belong and my training set accuracy improved a lot but my validation set accuracy did not. Why is that? what am I missing?

I am using a neural network with 2 hidden layers, 20 neurons each (I've tested a few possible architectures and this one gave me the best results).

After adding the new features Im now with 64 features, distinguishing between 3 different classes.

thanks for your help!

Comment: It ts called overfitting.. you train "too much" your model starts considering the "noise" in your training set so when you validate your results get worst.

Comment: @Picarus is correct. The best thing you can do is to experiment by adding one feature at a time, then two etc. and plot training & validation accuracy against the different cases. You keep the setup that increases validation accuracy. If validation accuracy falls then you face overfitting and you need to discard the extra information because it is "too specialized" for your training data

Comment: And what should be constant through all iterations? number of neurons in the hidden layers? lambda (regularization factor)? number of training iterations? etc..

Comment: There are no correct answer. Increasing the number of iterations leads to overfitting, the same goes for increasing the number of neurons and layers. As with many subjects in AI, you should consider Occam's Razor and use as few neurons and layers as possible.

Comment: The parameters of your NN should also be part of your model: number of neurons on each layer, number of layers, learning parameter. You should run a crossvalidation to find the best set of parameters. For that your dataset is split in 3 parts: training, validation and testing. So, your variables are: your features but also your NN structure parameters. The problem with that is that it becomes computationally expensive and going through all the combinations may not be affordable. You should explore your variables to see which ones are more promising. Are you restricted to NN? give more detail.